# Repeat process until condition is satisfied

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
   1. A=rnorm(100,mean=0, sd=30)
   2. B1=A+rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=10); B2=A+rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=30); B3=A+rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=50)
   3. d=data.frame(A, B1,B2,B3)
   4. c=cor(d)^2
   5. r=c[2,1]/c[4,1]
```

I would like to repate lines `1-4`. until the condition `1.6 <=r <=3.5` is satisfied.

I.e. I would like to generate `A, B1, B2, B3` so that they satisfy the criteria that `r` is between the values `1.6` and `3.5` if the value of `r` falls out of that range I would like to repeat `1-4.` until it falls within the range.

Comment: I was thinking of using while() or something like that.. or a complicated for loop with if statements, I guess ifelse() would be ideal but I'm not sure how to list so many commands within ifelse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` can be useful in this situation.

```
set.seed(1)
r<- 0
while(!(1.6 <=r & r <=3.5)){
  r <- r
  A=rnorm(100,mean=0, sd=30)
  B1=A+rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=10); B2=A+rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=30); B3=A+rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=50)
  d=data.frame(A, B1,B2,B3)
  c=cor(d)^2
  r=c[2,1]/c[4,1]
  print(r)
}
[1] 4.530864
[1] 2.600124
```

It repeats only twice and finds a value meeting the condition, 2.600124 and then stops, because the first value (4.530864) does not fall into the range.